# Is there some way to fake merge tracking in Subversion 1.4?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I'm interacting with a 3rd party Subversion repository that is still running version 1.4 and the likelihood of getting them to upgrade is close to nil. So, of course, my work with this repository is some of the most merge-heavy work I've ever done and and I don't have any mergeinfo to work with.

Is there a good workflow anyone can recommend for tracking branching and merging in a 1.4 repository? Something with commit messages and/or properties? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is no merge tracking native to Subversion 1.4. Since Subversion has a native API, it is quite possible that some third party client has a built in merge tracker.

Pre-1.5, you were suppose to track merges by adding the merge information as part of your commit message. You also tried to avoid doing cherry-picking and merging from anything but the root of the project. Otherwise, things started getting pretty complex pretty fast.

I would use tags to mark my merge points. For example, I would have a tag `5.1->trunk` that marked my last merge point from the 5.1 branch to the trunk. Looking for a tag rather than going through the SVN log looking for merge comments was a lot easier.

I guess you could also use the `svn:merge-info` property since it's not being used in your revision of Subversion. Might be very helpful if you format it as the standard svn:mergeinfo property format. Maybe one day, they will upgrade, and your "svn:mergeinfo" properties might do you some good.

Then again, this might be the perfect reason why you shouldn't use the svn:mergeinfo property. Mess up its formatting, and the post-1.5 version of Subversion they upgrade too will throw conniptions. You're better off using something like `local:mergeinfo` until you server is upgraded (if it ever is upgraded).

Answer (score 0):

David is right, Subversion didn't have any merge tracking support built into the 1.4.  However, there is the [svnmerge](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) script that the current Subversion merge tracking feature was modeled after.  Some projects, like Python, where using it successfully to maintain both long and short term branches.

Depending on the project, using [bzr-svn](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-svn-projects.html), [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html), or [hg-subversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/overview) might get you closer to what you're looking for.  IMO, bzr-svn works rather well, and supports real merging of branches (the other require you to use a rebase workflow).  I've used it successfully on several projects, but there are some caveats.  For instance, if your project uses externals, then the story with any of these tools is far less appealing, as none of them support externals.